# Fallo con el archivo .env

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo en phpmyadmin 2 bases de datos, una llamada `bolsa` y otra llamada `juego`.
Quiero en ambas colocar las tablas de mi pagina web.
En el primer caso, pongo este código en mi archivo .env:

```
DB_DATABASE=bolsa
```

Y objeto esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para hacer lo mismo en la otra BBDD, cambio el código en .env:

```
DB_DATABASE=juego
```

Pero la cosa falla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece ser que en vez de hacerse la migración en `juego`, se hizo en `bolsa` otra vez. ¿Cómo arreglo esto?

Comment: puede ser que el queue esté corriendo o que tenga los valores en cache, aquí hay pistas https://stackoverflow.com/a/43540391/1423096

Comment: @aloMalbarez Pues ha funcionado, aunque vaya lata va a ser que se pueda anclar la BBDD utilizada y deba hacer una limpieza.